# Access an specific python version in a system with more than one python environment

Tags: python

I am trying to access python 3.4 from the terminal under windows 7.
I have installed Python through Anaconda distribution and with it I installed python 2.7 by default and python 3.4 in a virtual environment.

when I run this:

```
c:\Anaconda\envs\Python34\Python.exe setup.py
```

I get:

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

So how can I call python 3.4 from the terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just ran python 3.4 there? That message is coming from setup.py

Comment: Please explain what the problem with what you already did is.

Answer (score 1):

Make the first line of `myscript.py` a hashbang:

```
#!c:\Anaconda\envs\Python34\Python.exe
```

If you only have a single Python 3.x interpreter installed then the hashbang can be simpler:

```
#!python3
```

Then run the script with `py`:

```
C:\> py myscript.py
```

or just:

```
C:\> myscript.py
```

Comment: same here, 
 
I get : 'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0):

Python for windows ships with a launcher that managed multiple versions:

```
py -2 my2script.py
py -3 my3script.py
py -3.4 mynew3script.py
```

Comment: I get : 'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Then it's not on your path.

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera, it gets installed into C:\windows when you install Python 3.x. Did you install from a standard distribution?

Comment: Might be, so, shall I add 'c:\Anaconda\envs\Python34\Python.exe' to the system path?

Comment: @Duncan I installed python 2.7 from anaconda distribution and later added python 3.4 as a virtual environment.

Comment: No, you want `py.exe` on your path, not `Python.exe`. Try reinstalling Python 3.4 as it seems your installation is messed up.

Comment: I don't know Anaconda, but I see it lets you install a 3.4 virtual env after only installing 2.7. Perhaps that is broken: `py.exe` isn't included in 2.7 and maybe they don't install it for 3.4 if you only asked for a virtualenv. Try a standalone 3.4 installation to get py.exe installed. It should then work with your existing virtualenv though you may need to edit the config to tell it the location.